# Regex allow search for one string [fsp] and number

Tags: regex, search, video, string-matching, subtitle

i use aegisub to edit subtitle most ass subtitle i need to edit all fsp value to 0 the original subtitle have many value of fsp  like fsp-0.667 and fsp1.333 and fsp-4 so i need Regex search for fsp with number like above, it's painful 
when i edit thousand of line to edit all fsp  to fsp-0 manually

---edit----
fsp mean font spacing
i translate ass English subtitle to Arabic, English  have space between characters but Arabic not have any space, so English translator use fsp with many value as he like but Arabic translator should remove all space between characters that mean set fsp with any value to fsp-0 otherwise no one can read subtitle, so i can't edit thousand of line to set fsp to fsp-0, yes i can search for fsp-0.667 and replace with fsp-0 but only 100 line have fsp-0.667 and next 70 have different value and next x line have fsp-x.

aegisub support regex with search and replace so i need sipmple script can search for  fsp with numbers

---edit2----
what i need is regex code search for fsp string with it value [numbers]
[like seach for string fsp and seach for the numbers came after fsp]

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you post some example code, explain what "fsp" is, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
/fsp-?[0-9.]+/fsp-0/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all fsp tag using this Regular expressions pattern:

```
\{\\fsp-?((\d+)|(\d+\.\d+))\}
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yHkB7n/1)